# I need to show the results of a calculated field on the NEW ITEM Sharepoint list form...thoughts?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, json, microsoft-lists

So, I have a calculated field that is calculated based on how other columns are populate on the NEW ITEM SharePoint list form.

I am new but I understand that calculated field will not show on the form.

So, wondering if backend data for that calculated field could be copied from another column to show on form?

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Whats the calculation?